# Eclipse plugin to automatically copy to clipboard anything I select

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that can automatically copy to clipboard anything I select some text in Eclipse. Just like [Auto Copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg?hl=en) on Chrome.

If possible, it should work for Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[DragKing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/19479/903) does not work for Eclipse.