# Microsoft Word Add-in to automatically copy to clipboard anything I select

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, microsoft-word

I am looking for a Microsoft Word Add-in that can automatically copy to clipboard anything I select some text in Microsoft Word. Just like [Auto Copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg?hl=en) in Chrome.

If possible, it should work for Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Microsoft Word 2013 Professional.

(Reason: I often use the computer hands free.)

Comment: Personally I don't find control-C that hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DragKing](http://m.en.softonic.com/app/dragking), it will do exactly what you need. It isn't a Microsoft Word plug-in but rather a Windows open source, AHK-based *donationware* app (which really shouldn't matter anyways). There isn't an extensive Word plug-in database that I'm aware of either (like there is for Firefox), so this will probably be your best option. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, great program. It seems to work in most applications except a few ones such as Eclipse.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helps!